# Java Lambda in Intellij: Expected not null but the lambda body is not value-compatible

Tags: lambda, java-8

Trying to filter a collection using a stream, and trying to pass the following lambda to filter() a Set, which gives the arcane error in the title:

```
unmatchedIncomingFields.stream().filter(s-> s.matches(fieldMatchPattern))
```

Meanwhile, creating a Predicate object works:

```
unmatchedIncomingFields.stream().filter(new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String s) {
        return s.matches(fieldMatchPattern);
    }
});
```

According to the JLS, a lambda body is "value-compatible" if every control path returns a value. matches() always gets called and always returns a boolean, so I don't understand what the problem is.

I've also tried all kinds of variations of the same lambda- with and without parentheses and argument types and using expression and block-with-return bodies.

Comment: what's the type of `unmatchedIncomingFields` ?

Comment: Can you include a small reproductible example, and also the compiler version you are using?

Comment: @AlexisC. The compiler is 1.8.0_77. I'm working on getting a demonstration.

Comment: what's the generic type of the elements in the Set, is it `Set<String>` or just `Set`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue looks to be incorrect, or at least somewhat misleading, error highlighting within IntelliJ, confusing where the actual error was.

The filter occurs within another lambda for a map() operation which I had not specified a return for yet, and for some reason, IntelliJ highlights the inner lambda for the filter, making it look like it is the one with the error.

Comment: Correct, similar thing has just happened to me. Thank you!

Comment: This looks like an actual bug in Intellij, as the same thing just happened to me. Have we filed an issue yet?